# How to generate random potential in tight binding model?

Tags: solid-state-physics, anderson-localization

Tight binding model exhibit Anderson localization. In Anderson localization there is no interaction b/w particles. But in order to generate random potential in tight binding model if we switch on time varying electric or magnetic field will the particles start interacting with each other? Can someone give me example of physical system ?

Answer (score 1):

No, the particles do not interacts with each other.

Anderson localisation is a single-particle effect. 
 In any potential, the total wavefunction is the sum of the incident and reflected wave on/from the potential barrier. 
 In a random potential, all the reflections interfere destructively such that you cannot have a wavefunction build-up at long-distance, but instead it's exponentially decaying. 
 Hence localised.

Comment: Then how we can generate random potential?By external fields?

Comment: And what is meant by single particle effect?Tight binding model is the example of Anderson localization and in this localization we consider particles on the lattice that can hop then how it is single particle effect?

Comment: Well you just add a random number to energy level of each lattice site.
Experimentally, you either project a speckle pattern, or you interfere lattices with incommensurate wavelengths. Both lead to random energy offsets between energy levels.

Comment: Single-particle effect means that the equation of motion is fully linear, i.e. you do not need to take into account interactions *between* particles. If interactions were allowed, you would have a non-linaer term in the TDSE ($\propto \Psi^4$) and the solution would be the full many-body wavefunction. So single particle means that it's not many-body. 

If you turn on interactions, you'll see that localisation survives *despite* interactions -  an effect called *Many-body Localisation*

Comment: Sorry can you please explain a bit more about how to generate random potential in lattice experimentaly without applying Electric or magnetic field?

Comment: Experimentally you usually do this either wth photonics (waveguides) or cold atoms (optical lattices). I do not anything about the former, so I'll talk about the latter. You use EM fields (lasers) just becaue they are hadny, tuneable and focussed to small regions. Techincally you could use random magnetic fields, gravitainal fields or what not. <br> To generate a speckle potential, you shine a laser onto a DMD with a random pattern, and then shine the result onto a 2D sheet of cold atoms.

Comment: So it means that in Anderson localization system can interact with the environment? if we shine laser beam will the particle not absorb energy?if yes is it not similar to considering interaction b/w particles

Comment: Tight binding means that the potential energy is much stronger than the kinetic energy, so your atoms are localised in each lattice sites. If the potential is generated within a condensed matter system, then it just means that you have impurities and defects such that the Coulomb potential is distorted randmoly on each site and gives rise to a random energy. <br> If you are generating the potential with lasers (in the context of optical lattices and cold atoms), then being "tight binding" means that you are only seeing the AC Startk shift of the light (the potential poart), not the scattering.

Comment: Interactions between atoms is completely different than interactions with light.